# PDOStatement::execute() returns true but the data is not updated

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I don't know why, this prepared query doesn't work: The following php code is correct (not any warning or notice), but the correponding datas are not updated. For similar update the db are correctly updated, but not for this table.

```
<?php

  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost', 'root', ''); 
  $sql = 'UPDATE `ml_user` SET `username` = :username, `password` = :password, `email` = :email, `active` = :active, `last_login` = :last_login WHERE `id_user` = :id_user';
  $sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  var_dump($sth); // object(PDOStatement)#39 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(165) "UPDATE `ml_user` SET `username` = :username, `password` = :password, `email` = :email, `active` = :active, `last_login` = :last_login WHERE `id_user` = :id_user" }
  $datas = array(
    ':id_user' => 1, ':username' => 'my username',
    ':password' => 'ae25ff724d069dcb1a7fff05616ad6abc1',
    ':email' => 'username@example.com',
    ':active' => 1, ':last_login' => 1382990654,
  );
  $res = $sth->execute($datas);
  var_dump($res); // bool(true)
```

The sql table

```
CREATE TABLE `ml_user` (
 `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `email` varchar(127) NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `password` char(50) NOT NULL,
 `logins` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `last_login` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_user`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq_username` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq_email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: do you need a : in front of each key in your 'datas' array?

Comment: no, with or without : , same result : no error

Comment: put it in a try catch block

Comment: change 'username' => ':my username' to ':username' => 'my username'

Comment: no error thrown at all. I even checked there is enough disk space

Comment: and if I replace ":password" by "zz:password" for example, I have an error "Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40143/discussion-between-asenar-and-ryan)

Comment: Oh, how I love these suggestion in comments...

Comment: sorry Ryan, but that's not the problem either, wrong replacement in my edition, sorry

Comment: @Ryan, for what it's worth, in recent versions of PHP, you can pass parameters to execute() without the ':' prefix in the array keys. It used to be needed, but not anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `execute()` returns **true** it means the statement was "successful," but it doesn't mean it changed anything. It just means there was no error.

- It may have matched zero rows because of conditions in the WHERE clause. That's still considered a "success." You can try a `SELECT` with the same WHERE clause, and fetch the results, to confirm that it matches rows.
- It may have matched one or more rows, but the values you are setting are already the values on those rows. You can call `$sth->rowCount()` after you execute, to find out how many rows the UPDATE *affected* (this may be less than the number of rows it matched).
- If you have more than one copy of this table, you should double-check that the change has been made in the database you are reading. It happens to me sometimes -- I forget to change an application configuration file, and I don't realize I'm updating the wrong database.

---

*This turned out to be the problem -- a variation on the third point:*

- If you work on more than one server, also double-check you are checking the changes on the correct mysql server.

Comment: thanks for theses suggestions, but still stuck with that. The WHERE clause return 1 row. and rowCOunt() return (int)0 . Also thanks for the suggestion about the wrong database, but I checked that already !

Comment: If the statement was successful, but rowCount() returns 0, then you must be setting the values that the row already has.

Comment: that's not the case either, username and password are different in the table and in the php array

Answer (score 1):

If there was no error and no data updated then no matching row were found.